# FBConnect iOS SDK publish_action Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, fbconnect

I must say I feel like an idiot right now. :) I've been up and down Facebook, Google and StackOverflow and still cannot get the answer to what I am doing wrong! :) I've looked at both Facebook examples: `Hackbook` and `WishList`. `Wishlist` is obviously the one that should tell me what to do, but **ALL** the examples I've seen have the **OBJECT** part as a URL. I do not necessarily desire this, as I just want the post to say **(this user) is playing [MyGame]**.

Ok here's my goal. I have an iPhone game. I want to do what Spotify does when you listen to a song, which posts to timeline and ticker. I'd also like to use this to post the player's score on the user's timeline and ticker.

I setup Open Graph with an action called `Play` and an object called `Game` along with it's aggregator. I think I also will need an action called `Score`?

Anyways, I can successfully post to a user's wall using `feed` dialog, but that's not what I want for the `Play` action.

Here's a concise version of what I got so far, any help is much appreciated:

Couple Notes:
I have a singleton `FacebookInfo` which takes care of handling Facebook delegates and stuff. I also have a `FacebookUser` class which hold the current user's info for the current session, populated when calling `me`. I also have a DLog method which simply does an NSlog only on debug mode.

When a user clicks the `Play` button in my game, I would like to call my method `[[Facebook sharedInfo] publishAction:@"play"]` below. I'm passing an `NSString` as action so later I can call the same method and use an action like `Score` and just modify the post accordingly.

```
@interface FacebookInfo : NSObject  {
    Facebook *_facebook;
    FacebookUser *_facebookUser;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
@property (nonatomic, retain) FacebookUser *facebookUser;

+(id)sharedInfo;
-(BOOL)isFacebookAuthenticated;
-(void)fbDidLogout;
-(void)getMe;
-(void)publishFeed;
-(void)publishWithAction:(NSString *)action;

@end
```

```
static FacebookInfo *facebookInfo = nil;


@implementation FacebookInfo


@synthesize facebook = _facebook;
@synthesize facebookUser = _facebookUser;


#pragma mark - Custom Methods


-(void)getMe {
    DLog(@"**********");
/* when forcing FBConnect to show inline dialog instead of using SSO, this works.
apparently this fails when using SSO, error:
Err message: (null)
Err code: 10000
*/
    [[self facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self]; 
}


-(void)publishWithAction:(NSString *)action {
    DLog(@"**********");

    if ([action isEqualToString:@"play"]) {
        // Build the params list
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        // all sample have this pointing to a URL. Do i really need to do that?
        [params setValue:kFBAppNameSpace forKey:@"game"];
        // I know I may need more parameters, but which are required?
        // Do I need to add the one's that Facebook Javascript examples have, 
        // like title, description? I think it's here where I'm mostly confused.

        // Make the Graph API call to add to the wishlist
        [[self facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/[myappnamespace]:play" 
                                andParams:params
                            andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                              andDelegate:self];

        [params release];
    }
}


-(void)publishFeed {
    DLog(@"**********");
    /*
This works perfectly fine
*/
    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

    NSDictionary *actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"Get The App",@"name",
                                  kFBAppURL,@"link",
                                  nil],
                                 nil];

    NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

    NSString *app_id = kFBAppID;
    NSString *user_message_prompt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Post to Your Wall!"];
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[MyGameName]"];
    NSString *caption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has gotten a score of %@!",[[self facebookUser] firstName],[[[GameInfo sharedGameInfo] scoreTotal] stringValue]];
    NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can you beat this score?!"];
    NSString *link = kFBAppURL;
    NSString *picture = kFBAppImage;

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   app_id, @"app_id",
                                   user_message_prompt,  @"user_message_prompt",
                                   name, @"name",
                                   caption, @"caption",
                                   description, @"description",
                                   link, @"link",
                                   picture, @"picture",
                                   actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                                   nil];

    [[self facebook] dialog:@"feed"
                  andParams:params
                andDelegate:self];
}


-(BOOL)checkForPreviousAccessToken {
    DLog(@"**********");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        DLog(@"FB: Token Exists!");
        [[self facebook] setAccessToken:[defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]];
        [[self facebook] setExpirationDate:[defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]];
    }
    if (![[self facebook] isSessionValid]) {
        DLog(@"FB: Authorizing...");
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"publish_stream",
                                @"publish_actions",
                                @"offline_access",
                                nil];
        [[self facebook] authorize:permissions];
        [permissions release];
    } else {
        DLog(@"FB: Authorized!!!");
        // show logged in
        [self getMe];
    }

    return [[self facebook] isSessionValid];
}


-(BOOL)isFacebookAuthenticated {
    DLog(@"**********");

    return [self checkForPreviousAccessToken];
}


-(void)extendAccessTokenIfNeeded {
    DLog(@"**********");

    [[self facebook] extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];
    [[FacebookInfo sharedInfo] getMe];
}


-(void)logout {
    DLog(@"**********");

    [[self facebook] logout:self];
}


#pragma mark - FBConnect Delegate Methods

-(void)fbDidLogin {
    DLog(@"**********");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[[self facebook] accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[[self facebook] expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [self getMe];
}


- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
    DLog(@"**********");


}


- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt {
    DLog(@"**********");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:expiresAt forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}


-(void)fbDidLogout {
    DLog(@"**********");

    // Remove saved authorization information if it exists
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]) {
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}


- (void)fbSessionInvalidated {
    DLog(@"**********");


}


#pragma mark - FBRequestDelegate Methods

/**
 * Called when the Facebook API request has returned a response. This callback
 * gives you access to the raw response. It's called before
 * (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result,
 * which is passed the parsed response object.
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    DLog(@"**********");

    //DLog(@"received response");
}

/**
 * Called when a request returns and its response has been parsed into
 * an object. The resulting object may be a dictionary, an array, a string,
 * or a number, depending on the format of the API response. If you need access
 * to the raw response, use:
 *
 * (void)request:(FBRequest *)request
 *      didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    DLog(@"**********");
    //code removed for this example
}

/**
 * Called when an error prevents the Facebook API request from completing
 * successfully.
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    DLog(@"**********");

    DLog(@"Err message: %@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error_msg"]);
    DLog(@"Err code: %d", [error code]);
    if ([error code] == 190) {
        // logout
    } else {
        DLog(@"There was an error making your request.");
    }
}


#pragma mark - Singleton Methods


+ (id)sharedInfo {
    //DLog(@"**********");

    @synchronized(self) {
        if(facebookInfo == nil)
            facebookInfo = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return facebookInfo;
}


+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    DLog(@"**********");

    return [[self sharedInfo] retain];
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    DLog(@"**********");

    return self;
}


- (id)retain {
    DLog(@"**********");

    return self;
}


- (unsigned)retainCount {
    DLog(@"**********");

    return UINT_MAX; //denotes an object that cannot be released
}


- (oneway void)release {
    DLog(@"**********");

    // never release
}


- (id)autorelease {
    DLog(@"**********");

    return self;
}


- (id)init {
    DLog(@"**********");

    if ((self = [super init]) != NULL) {
        //Init
        [self setFacebook:[[[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kFBAppID urlSchemeSuffix:kFBUrlSchemeSuffix andDelegate:self] autorelease]];
        [self setFacebookUser:[[[FacebookUser alloc] init] autorelease]];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    DLog(@"**********");

    // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
    DLog(@"Release FacebookInfo...");
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

```
@implementation AppDelegate_iPhone

// Add for Facebook SSO support (4.2+)
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    [[[FacebookInfo sharedInfo] facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}


// Add for Facebook SSO support (pre 4.2)
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    [[[FacebookInfo sharedInfo] facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    DLog(@"**********");

    [[FacebookInfo sharedInfo] extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];
}
```

Wow, I know this is a long post, but I hope someone can help point me in the right direction.

## UPDATE 1: (2012/18/02)

Ok. So I settled for making a page which contains the og meta-data which I did not want to do and supplied the url for my object. As per the FB Documentation, found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/#mechanics):

```
Open Graph Mechanics

When users take an action in your app, such as cook the Stuffed Cookie, the app calls a Graph API to create a new cook action that connects the user with the Stuffed Cookie object. This is accomplished by issuing a HTTP POST to the user’s /me/myapp:cook connection with the URL of the recipe object. Facebook will then crawl the object URL, read the metadata, and connect the object to user's Graph via the action.

The diagram below illustrates the process:

User takes an action in the app, such as "cook" a "recipe"
App calls a Graph API /me/action:object=Object_URL
Facebook will crawl the object URL, read its meta tags and connects the object to the user's Graph via the action.
```

It would be cool if we can define these things in the app itself as params for cases where I do not need a website for.

Comment: I wanted to do the same, like, publishing actions without creating an associated web page with meta tags. So, essentially, it worked only *after* creating the page. Is that correct ?

Comment: This is correct. As of now, 3/9/2012, I could only accomplish this by creating a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 4/21/12 Facebook requires you to have created a page to get the data desired.